# "One-Sided Hungarian" or "Hungarian for Roommate Problem"

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, bipartite-graphs

The Hungarian algorithm is a solution to a two-sided matching problem. There are similar "one-sided" matching problems, such as the [roommates problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem). Like the Hungarian, roommates need to be matched to another. The weight of a pairwise match is $w_{ij}$, and your goal is to find the matching that maximize the total weights.

However unlike the Hungarian, the agents are not differentiated into two sides. Any roommate can pair with any other roommate. Each possible pair has a weight, and like the Hungarian, the goal is to find the roommate arrangements with the maximum possible weights.

Is there a known algorithmic solution to "one-sided" matching problems?

Comment: There is a modification of the [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) that handles weighted graphs.

Comment: A solution to the weighted version of the stable roommates problem is implemented in the R package `matchingR` with the `roommate` function. It is quite fast based on my limited testing. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matchingR/vignettes/matchingR-intro.html

Comment: After looking more closely at your question, I realized that you are not describing the stable roommates problem, but rather a maximum matching problem. The blossom algorithm mentioned by @MishaLavrov solves this problem.

Comment: The `maxmatching` R package implements the blossom algorithm. Beware, it seems to provide the solution in different formats depending on if the graph is bipartite. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421942/9463489) StackOverflow answer for an example usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question, and the details matter in this case. To clarify, let $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$, further $[2n]=\{1,\dots,2n\}$ and $\mathcal E=\binom{[2n]}{2}=\{e\subseteq[2n]:|e|=2\}$. Let $K_{2n}=([2n],\mathcal E)$ be the complete graph on $2n$ vertices and let $\mathcal M=\{M\in\binom{\mathcal E}{n}:\bigcup_{e\in M}e=[2n]\}$ be the set of perfect matchings in $K_{2n}$, which are $n$ sets of size $2$ that form a partition of $[2n]$.
Finally, we add weights, that is, for each $e\in\mathcal E$ we fix some $w_e\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. For a perfect matching $M\in\mathcal M$ let $W(M)=\sum_{e\in M}w_e$ be the weight of $M$.

My understanding is that you want to find an algorithm that outputs a perfect matching $M\in\mathcal M$ such that for all $M'\in\mathcal M$ we have $W(M')\le W(M)$. I hope I got that right.

As long as we consider $K_{2n}$, it doesn't matter if we consider matchings, maximal matchings, maximum matchings or perfect matchings, because the sets of maximal, maximum and perfect matchings coincide, and any maximum weight matching is a perfect matching without loss of generality (i.e. up to edges with trivial weight). If we consider arbitrary graphs, we have to pay more attention.

I also want to stress that finding a stable matching for the roommates problem differs from the problem at hand. For example, a stable matching does not always exist, a maximum weight matching does.

With this being said, there exist algorithms that find solutions to the maximum weight matching problem in $K_{2n}$ with runtime $\mathcal O(n^3)$, by Edmonds (1965), by Gabow (1974), by Lawler (1976), and by Gabow (1990). More general, for graphs with $m$ edges these algorithms perform best in different regimes, Table 3 in [this contribution](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/papers/ApproxMWM-JACM.pdf) is an excellent overview. However, as pointed out in the general case maximum weight matchings are maximum weight maximal matchings, but may differ from maximum weight perfect matchings (which are maximum weight maximum matchings).

Comment: Thank you! I *think* your formalization is correct, however some of your LaTeX code isn't showing up right. I see square boxes for your binomial symbols, for exampele. Let me see if I can do something to fix it.

Comment: Also: I absolutely agree that the stable roommate problem ("SRP") is different than what we're talking about, insofar as it *stability* rather than "maximal weight." The similarity with SRP is simply that there's matching from the same sides.

Comment: Finally, let me check out the Goldberg and Karzanov 2004 solution. Is it the article? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-004-0505-z

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help with the display problems, everything is rendered fine on my side. Maybe try another browser or look for updates? If there's something I can do about it, let me know.  I checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) and Table 3 in [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/papers/ApproxMWM-JACM.pdf) (and just realized that I confused the tables).

Comment: I corrected the post, sorry for the confusion. The Goldberg and Karzanov algorithm was the one from Table 1, which is for cardinality matchings.